Is it possible to accomplish Cisco IOS "prefix-suppression" functionality in Junos?
I have a network of three Juniper routers:

ge-0/0/* and lo0.0 interfaces are in OSPF area 0. My goal is to have only the loopback addresses in OSPF, but as seen below, the network 10.7.0.4/31 used between the jr2 and jr3 is also seen in OSPF:
root@jr1> show route protocol ospf table inet.0

inet.0: 11 destinations, 19 routes (11 active, 0 holddown, 0 hidden)
+ = Active Route, - = Last Active, * = Both

2.2.2.2/32         *[OSPF/10] 00:29:09, metric 1
                    >  to 10.7.0.3 via ge-0/0/0.0
3.3.3.3/32         *[OSPF/10] 00:27:20, metric 1
                    >  to 10.7.0.1 via ge-0/0/1.0
10.7.0.4/31        *[OSPF/10] 00:21:36, metric 2
                       to 10.7.0.3 via ge-0/0/0.0
                    >  to 10.7.0.1 via ge-0/0/1.0
224.0.0.5/32       *[OSPF/10] 00:31:21, metric 1
                       MultiRecv

root@jr1>

As a comparison, here is the output of sh ip route ospf from a Cisco IOS device from an identical setup, but all the routers have prefix-suppression configured:
cr1#sh ip route ospf
Codes: L - local, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route, H - NHRP, l - LISP
       a - application route
       + - replicated route, % - next hop override, p - overrides from PfR

Gateway of last resort is not set

      2.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
O        2.2.2.2 [110/2] via 10.7.0.3, 03:24:58, GigabitEthernet2
      3.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
O        3.3.3.3 [110/2] via 10.7.0.1, 03:24:38, GigabitEthernet3
cr1#

Is there a way to accomplish this with Juniper routers? I know that there is no identical configuration parameter to prefix-suppression in Junos and as far as I know, it's not possible to control this with route policies because 10.7.0.4/31 is an OSPF internal route.

I don't mean to sound obtuse, but what is your use case? Juniper does not implement what you're looking for exactly, but depending on what you want to do there might be an alternative.

@JordanHead I have an iBGP full mesh between routers loopbacks and I'm exporting direct routes into iBGP. As OSPF has a lower route preference than BGP, then this causes a so to say exception or irregularity where the network 10.7.0.4/31 used between the jr2 and jr3 is learned by OSPF and not by BGP as rest of the direct networks. I guess this isn't a problem, but ideally it seems to be cleaner or more elegant if IGP is used indeed only for the /32 loopbacks.

JunOS doesn't have a configuration statement like that as far as I'm aware, but you could however solve this with an import policy. This is untested, from the top of my head, but I think this will work:
policy-statement import-ospf {
    term reject {
        from protocol direct;
        then reject;
    }
    term accept {
        then accept;
    }
}

This would reject al directly connected routes and accept all other prefixes. Of course, you could change this to a policy to only accept specific routes (for example by matching the interface).
You can then apply this policy to the OSPF routing configuration:
set protocols ospf import import-ospf
You can read more about configuring OSPF routing policies in the Juniper documentation.

OSPF import policy would affect OSPF external routes from being installed into the routing table. Import nor export policies seem to have no affect on OSPF internal routes.
